# Python: Selenium cannot click XPath text element

Tags: python, angularjs, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to click element of this HTML:

```
<div class="feed-item__explanation" style="padding-left: 15px;">
     <a href="javascript:" ng-click="carinext()">Load more</a>
</div>
```

I'm using selenium to process this:

```
driver.get(url)
while True:
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[text()="Load more"]')
            print 'found'
        except Exception as e:
            print e
            break
```

That code can be processed and give output 'found'.
But when I'm trying to click that element,

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[text()="Load more"]').click()
```

I'm getting an error like this:

> Message: element not visible
>   (Session info: chrome=62.0.3202.94)

Is this a problem to process the AngularJS script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to scroll down to required element to be able to click it. Try below code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 

load_more = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Load more")))
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView();', load_more)
load_more.click()
```

Comment: I have tried it and gave an error with no messages, like `Message:`

Comment: What if to replace `load_more.click()` with `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Load more"))).click()`?

Comment: OH sorry, i got typo there, the first solution is the answer, many thanks!